# javascript onclick navigation (multiple layers) - how do I separate parent and child click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/kGw8y/1602/

```
$('#global-nav li:has(ul)').click(function(){
    $(this).find('> ul').stop().slideToggle(400); 
});
```

I found this that was originally using hover; however, I modified it to be on click instead.  If you look at the code, the child "sites" has links under it as well, but when you click on "sites" it also activates the main navigation closing it.

How do I separate the "parent" from "child" clicks?  I would prefer this to be a simple code that will work under multiple layers without having to add more and more code.

Also, how would I add an element to this code to where if the top layer "child" has links under it, it adds an arrow (still in black area) and when clicked, the arrow rotates to a down position.  Then when unselected, the arrow points back right.

Thanks for your help.

---

**EDIT**

How Do I make this work for a button outside of the navigation where Menu button drops down navigation?

Code:

```
<a id="menu_button" class="hidecontent_full hidecontent_condensed" href="#">Menu</a>

<div class="nav">
<ul>
<li class="first"><a href="#">New?</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="welcome.php">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="whoweare.php">Who We Are</a></li>
    <li><a href="whatwebelieve.php">What We Believe</a></li>
    <li><a href="whenandwhere.php">When and Where</a></li>
    <li><a href="staff.php">Crossroads Staff</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Next Steps</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="nextsteps.php">What is Next Steps?</a></li>
    <li><a href="connect.php">Connect</a></li>
    <li><a href="grow.php">Grow</a></li>
    <li><a href="serve.php">Serve</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Ministries</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="kidz.php">Childrens Ministry</a></li>
    <li><a href="fused.php">Student Ministry</a></li>
    <li><a href="connectgroups.php">Connect Groups</a>
    <li><a href="musicministry.php">Music Ministry</a></li>
    <li><a href="prayerrequests.php">Prayer Requests</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Resources</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="sermonarchives.php">Sermon Archives</a></li>
    <li><a href="ccb.php">Church Community Builder</a></li>
    <li><a href="parents.php">Parents</a></li>
    <li><a href="Biblereadingplans.php">Bible Reading Plans</a></li>
    <li><a href="recommendedbooks.php">Recommended Books</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="last"><a href="#">Events</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="merge.php">Merge</a></li>
    <li><a href="Christmasonthefarm.php">Christmas on the Farm</a></li>
    <li><a href="lovecamedown.php">Love Came Down</a></li>
    <li><a href="dinnerfor8.php">Dinner for 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="calendarofevents.php">Calendar of Events</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Give</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="howtogive.php">How to Give</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

</ul>
</div>  <!-- navigation -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

returning false keeps event from bubbling through dom and triggering other selected elements.

## edit II

the code is really the same, though:

## **[LAST FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1t3y34eg/43/)**

[NEW JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1t3y34eg/)

[OLD JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kGw8y/1604/)

js

```
$('#global-nav li:has(ul)').click(function(){
    $(this).find('> ul').slideToggle(400);
});

$('#menu_button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

css

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu_button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    width:200px;
    background:#444;
    color: white;
}
#global_nav {
    display: none;
}
.open ~ #global-nav {
    display: block;
    width:200px;
    background:#444;
}

#global-nav li a{
    padding:15px;
}
#global-nav a{
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
}
#global-nav ul ul{
    display:none;
    background:#000;
}
#global-nav ul ul a:hover{
    background:#222;
}
```

html

```
<a id="menu_button" class="hidecontent_full hidecontent_condensed" href="#">Menu</a>

<div id="global-nav">
<ul>
<li class="first"><a href="#">New?</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="welcome.php">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="whoweare.php">Who We Are</a></li>
    <li><a href="whatwebelieve.php">What We Believe</a></li>
    <li><a href="whenandwhere.php">When and Where</a></li>
    <li><a href="staff.php">Crossroads Staff</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Next Steps</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="nextsteps.php">What is Next Steps?</a></li>
    <li><a href="connect.php">Connect</a></li>
    <li><a href="grow.php">Grow</a></li>
    <li><a href="serve.php">Serve</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Ministries</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="kidz.php">Childrens Ministry</a></li>
    <li><a href="fused.php">Student Ministry</a></li>
    <li><a href="connectgroups.php">Connect Groups</a>
    <li><a href="musicministry.php">Music Ministry</a></li>
    <li><a href="prayerrequests.php">Prayer Requests</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Resources</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="sermonarchives.php">Sermon Archives</a></li>
    <li><a href="ccb.php">Church Community Builder</a></li>
    <li><a href="parents.php">Parents</a></li>
    <li><a href="Biblereadingplans.php">Bible Reading Plans</a></li>
    <li><a href="recommendedbooks.php">Recommended Books</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="last"><a href="#">Events</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="merge.php">Merge</a></li>
    <li><a href="Christmasonthefarm.php">Christmas on the Farm</a></li>
    <li><a href="lovecamedown.php">Love Came Down</a></li>
    <li><a href="dinnerfor8.php">Dinner for 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="calendarofevents.php">Calendar of Events</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Give</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="howtogive.php">How to Give</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

</ul>
</div>  <!-- navigation -->
```

Comment: But this doesn't seems to work, clicking child site closes the menu.

Comment: Once I plugged the code into my page, it broke because I am using a menu button outside of the navigation to launch the navigation drop down on click.  How would I modify the code to work, still keeping in mind my initial question.  I added an "edit" to my question showing my code

Comment: Well, except that it isn't working.  See how Menu is doing absolutely nothing? I need the navigation hidden completely until "Menu" is clicked, the the navigation slides down...then top level and child elements will be able to be used.  And then "menu" will also hide the navigation again

Comment: huh? I'm confused. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `event.stopPropagation()` in the click:

```
$('#global-nav li:has(ul)').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); // it stops the event to bubble up to the parent elems
    $(this).find('> ul').stop().slideToggle(400); 
});
```

Comment: Once I plugged the code into my page, it broke because I am using a menu button outside of the navigation to launch the navigation drop down on click.  How would I modify the code to work, still keeping in mind my initial question.  I added an "edit" to my question showing my code